# Changing themes and hot-corner settings from command-line

Tags: command-line, dconf, pantheon

I want to change the [elementary tweak themes](http://lmelinux.net/elementary-tweaks/) and [hot-corner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_hotspot) settings on my Elementary Luna (built on Ubuntu 12.04 "Precise") from the commandline.

With what command can I do this? I know how to make the changes from the GUI. Is there a way to capture settings made that way to feed into the commandline command?

Comment: So is my question still "too broad", or could you take it off hold yet?

Comment: You can post answers to your own question, and even accept them, once your question is put off hold/reopened. For that to happen **the question** needs to be improved. Pasting stuff like an answer in a question makes just makes it **much worse**. Please read the rules of this site in the help; improve your question (as a question) to make it acceptable (you already got the answer so you should be able to narrow down what you did wrong/missed in the first place); and once it is of hold, answer it. That also allows others to provide other and maybe even better answers.

Comment: @Anthon Is this better?

Comment: Sorry but not really. I can understand you leave the answer part in for now, but the part above that is still way to broad (partly IMO because of wrong terminology in the title), and the actual question is answerable with "yes" or "no". I might have time to try to improve the Q later today, as it is an interesting issue. You can always roll-back my changes if you don't like them. BTW nothing of this putting on hold is personal, just an effort to keep the site useful. And that starts with questions that are clear to a broader audience (the original posters normally know what the Q is about).

Comment: Voting to re-open.  I assume you will move everything after the first two paragraphs out of the question, and into an answer, when it's re-opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a partial answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175382/how-to-find-out-console-equivalents-of-ubuntu-system-settings-gui):

The command to use is 'gsettings` and the actual settings to use you can find by using:

```
dconf watch /
```

in the terminal, while you adjust the settings. You get a bunch of statements like this:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/theme
  'elementary'

/org/pantheon/desktop/gala/behavior/hotcorner-bottomleft
  'custom-command'

/org/pantheon/desktop/gala/behavior/hotcorner-bottomright
  'none'

/org/pantheon/desktop/gala/behavior/hotcorner-custom-command
  'xset dpms force off'
```

You want to reformat these lines into commands like this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme 'elementary'
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior hotcorner-custom-command 'xset dpms force off'
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior hotcorner-bottomleft 'custom-command'
```

Comment: Thanks for staying with us and splitting this of in a separate answer. The reopening took a bit longer than  expected.